# Symfony 6: the .css , js and images are not loaded in production

Tags: php, symfony

I encountered a problem displaying images and bootstrap files when deploying my Symfony 6 project.

I am in Symfony 6 training I have been working on a Symfony project for 1 month. I just deployed the project on shared LWS hosting using git pull. but the problems css, js, images are not loaded in PROD. Those in my audience, whether images or CSS and JS files, are not processed.

Notice: Everything works fine in DEV locally I have my css, js, images file in my public folder.

Here is my template which displays the images:

```
 <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
     <img src="{{asset('assets/images/1.jpg')}}" width="200px" alt="">
 </div>
```

Here is my basic template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Here is my `.htaccess` created by Apache pack:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # This Option needs to be enabled for RewriteRule, otherwise it will show an error like
    # 'Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden'
    Options +FollowSymlinks

    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Here is my `.htaccess` that I create to redirect the site in the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do the file `assets/images/1.jpg` exists in the directory `public/` on the server?

Comment: In first place i would suggest you to do a php bin/console cache:clear on your serveur , it's an usual problem with symfony when something work on one env but doesnt in others :)

Comment: Yes I cleared the caches manually on the server.
And the files are in the public/assets folder.

Comment: @A.L do you see a problem in the htaccess that I create because when I try to type the url following the images and the css and bootstrap are processed. here is the url: https://mondomaine.com/public

Comment: Can you set `public/` as the "root" of your hosting? So that `example.com/assets/images/1.jpg` works directly, instead of `example.com/public/assets/images/1.jpg`.